# onclick event with object as parameter in quotes

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dom-events

Working with the Google maps and places API, I am rendering infowindows for each marker that gets generated by a function **generateInfoWindow(location)**.

In there I create a string **HTML** that will be passed to the Google maps markers content attribute.

**Function**

```
function generateInfoWindow(location) {
  var html = "<div class = 'infowindowContainer'>" +
    "<span class = 'infoWindowHeader'>" + location.name + "</span>" +
    "<div class = 'row'>" +
    "<span class = 'col-xs-12'> ... : " + getInfoWindowDetails(location).adress + "</span>" +
    "<span class = 'col-xs-12'> ... : " + getInfoWindowDetails(location).open_hours + "</span>";

  if (location.offers.length > 0) {
    html +=
      "<span class = 'col-xs-12 iwOffers'> ... </span>" +
      "</div>" + //ends row
      "<div class = 'infoWindowCircleContainer'>";
    for (var i = 0; i < location.offers.length; i++) {
      html += "<span class = 'infoWindowCircle'>" + location.offers[i].offer_text + "</span>";
    }
    html += "</div>" //CircleContainer
  }

  html += "<span class = 'showMore' onclick = 'processWin(" + location + ")'>Show more</span>";
  html += "</div>"; //InfoWindowContainer the parent to all

  return html;
}

function processWin(location) {
  var winMarker;
  var winnerMap;
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: location.geometry.location,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    styles: googleMapsStyles
  };

  var locationId = location.place_id;
  var request = {
    placeId: locationId
  };

  places.getDetails(request, getWinnerDetails); //Where getWinnerDetails is the callback

  //since the location that we are passing in the callback function is the one we get as a JSON from the detailed search we are going to have to use our modified vars associated with the location here such as .keyword
  $("#foodType").text("Typ av mat : " + location.keyword);
  winnerMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('displayWinnerMap'), mapOptions);

  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    if (markers[i].placeId == location.place_id) {
      winMarker = markers[i];
      break;
    }
  }

  //setOfferCircles(location);
  winMarker.setMap(winnerMap);
  $("#displayWinPage").css("display", "block");
  doScroll("#displayWinPage");
}
```

Where I append the span with the class showMore I wish to append an onclick event that will call a method **processWin(location)** where I pass the location variable. (Will be multiple markers).

I can't seem to be able to pass the object location in the onclick event and
I don't understand why. Please do enlighten me.

Comment: Can't immediate see anything wrong in the given code when it comes assigning the `onclick`, so show us what `processWin()` does and what type its parameter `location` expects to be within that function.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/f15y7cnz/3/ Take a look at this fiddle and you will see the problem i mean. I can point towards a property of the object but can not pass it the object. alert(n) should still alert "object"

Comment: No, `alert` won't alert "object", it will throw an exception saying _"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"_ (check console and you'll see) ... but this work: http://jsfiddle.net/64hfweg2/ ... and because if this, we need to see your `processWin()` function

Comment: If you alert an object the response you will get is [Object object], try to just straight up alert n there. ProcessWin is an already working function but this is how it looks. (I use it in other parts of the webapp). I'll update my post

Comment: Actually, your initial fiddle does work, though it is a matter of how/when things gets loaded and positioned in the page. In this updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hr845nwp/ I make it wrap the `n` object in the `<head>` and on page load the `<span>` gets injected, and with that it works just fine, so how do you do in your code?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.  What is `getWinnerDetails`?  Are you accounting for the asynchronous behavior of the `.getDetails` call? What does the information in your question have to do with its title?

Answer (score 0):

An object converted to a string becomes [object object] and that is what you are passing as the parameter and not the object itself. Here is example code showing the wrong output

```
var location = {x : 100, y : 100};
var html = "<span class = 'showMore' onclick = 'processWin(" + location + ")'>Show more</span>";
console.log(html);

Output: <span class = 'showMore' onclick = 'processWin([object Object])'>Show more</span>
```

Using JSON.stringify(location) you get the object output correctly as shown below.

```
var location = {x : 100, y : 100};

var html = "<span class = 'showMore' onclick = 'processWin(" + JSON.stringify(location) + ")'>Show more</span>";

console.log(html);
Output:<span class = 'showMore' onclick = 'processWin({"x":100,"y":100})'>Show more</span>
```

Comment: Why don't you turn this into a runnable snippet? It's easy, and demonstrates your point much more clearly.